# Разбить файл txt на части по поиску

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, txt

в общем, задача довольно-таки нестандартная. Имеется файл такого вида:

```
======================================== SAMPLE 1 ========================================
Большой текст...
======================================== SAMPLE 2 ========================================
Большой текст
```

Ну и так далее, кол-во может быть не ограничено.
Суть в том, чтобы знаки `=` были как разделители и всё, что содержится в `sample 1`, попадало бы в первый файл. Всё, что в `sample 2` - во второй, и т. д.

**В конце** нужно иметь папку, в которой отдельно хранятся файлы txt с информацией.

Т.к. готового решения нет, склоняюсь к python, но я его практически не знаю, подскажите?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код:

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

# Регулярка для поиска строки с названием файла
pattern_file_name = re.compile('={40} (.+?) ={40}')

# Создание папки 'samples'
DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'samples'
DIR.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

with open('sample.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    file_name = ''
    file_obj = None
    is_file_header = True

    # Перебор строк файла
    for line in f:
        # Проверка наличия заголовка в файле
        match = pattern_file_name.search(line)
        if match:
            if file_obj:
                file_obj.close()

            # Открытие нового файла
            file_name = DIR / (match.group(1) + '.txt')
            file_obj = open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
            is_file_header = True
            continue

        if not file_name:
            continue

        # Запись строки в файл
        if is_file_header and len(line) > 50:
            file_obj.write(line[:50] + '\n' + line[50:])
            is_file_header = False

        else:
            file_obj.write(line)

    if file_obj:
        file_obj.close()
```

---

Создал файл `sample.txt`:

```
======================================== SAMPLE 1 ========================================
Большой текст...
======================================== SAMPLE 2 ========================================
Большой текст
```

Результатом будут файлы:

```
samples/
    SAMPLE 1.txt
    SAMPLE 2.txt
```

---

**UPD.**

Добавлена доработка, которая, при записи первой строки в файл, проверяет, что ее длина не больше 50 символов и в случае превышения, обрезает строку и переносит оставшуюся часть на следующую строку

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Осталась ещё одна проблемка, которую не учёл. Нужно в каждом файле после 50 символов переходить на новую строку, подскажите?

Comment: @Apelsin2020, странное условие, а зачем оно? И после первых 50 символов? Или после каждых 50 символов? А так, чтобы добавить перевод на новую строку используется код `file_obj.write('\n')`

Comment: Всё делается для программы, которой скармливаются эти файлы, первая строка будет как заголовок, а всё остальное просто тело статьи, а сейчас заголовки слишком большие

Comment: Может проще написать ещё один скрипт, который будет просто открывать уже созданные файлы и добавлять переход на новую строку?

Comment: @Apelsin2020, добавил флаг и проверку длины первой строки новых файлов. Если длина превышает 50 символов, то первые 50 символов записываются на одной строке, а оставшиеся символы на следующей. Возможно, придется ограничиваться первыми 49 + <символ переноса>, но это зависит от той программы, что вы используйте

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё работает

Answer (score 1):

```
# открываем и читаем общий большой файл,
# который должен лежать рядом с нашим py-файлом (с этим скриптом)
bigfile = open('mybigfile.txt', 'r') 
lines = bigfile.readlines() 

# данный алгоритм пропустит первые строки файла, 
# если файл не начинается с разделителей
file = None

# Индекс очередного файла
file_index = 1
for line in lines: 
    # Если строка начинается со знаков равно (допустим пяти),
    # то это повод завести себе новый файл
    if line.strip().startwith('====='):
        # Если уже был открыт предыдущий файл, то закрыть его
        if file:
            file.close() 
        # создаем следующий файл 
        file = open('myfile_{}.txt'.format(file_index), 'w') 
        # Обновляем нумератор файлов
        file_index += 1

    # Если файл создан, то пишем в него
    if file:    
        file.writelines(L) 

# Если имеется какой-либо созданный файл, то закрыть его
if file:
    file.close()
```

Comment: **1)** Если файл большой, то это `bigfile.readlines()` может не влезть в оперативную память, т.к. сначала весь файл будет считан и помещен в память, а после возвращен как список строк. **2)** не хватает создание папки с созданными файлами :)

Comment: @gil9red да, так и будет. Но, правильное решение уже дано, а мое пусть будет за компанию :)